How to go about linking external data to every word in a paragraph and access the external data even when the words are moved around?
Apologies there is no code yet as I'm not sure where to begin. I'm using python.
I am using whisper-timestamped to transcribe an audio file and create a json file that contains the timecode (start & end) of every word in an audio file.
I want to be able to display the words (in their original sequence) in a text document
and then cut and paste the words in any order I wish.
Then to be able to access the original timecodes of each word regardless of their new postion
For example:
I'm not sure where to begin.
Produces:
I'm (00.00) not (00.01) sure (00.02) where (00.04) to (00.05) begin (00.07)
Timecodes data 'stays' with each word as I reorder them.
not (00.01) begin (00.07) I'm (00.00) sure (00.02)
How would I go about trying to do this? Where is a good place to start?

"Then to be able to access the original timecodes of each word regardless of their new postion" - so keep them both together to begin with then ...? Use a regular expression to split this into parts, I'm (00.00), not (00.01), etc., and then write them to your text file line by line.
